# Eigen 3 - Slicing a MatrixXd to reverse the columns order

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, eigen3

I need to reverse the order of the columns of a MatrixXd using RcppEigen.

In `R` I would simply do

```
> M = matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> M = M[, 3:1]
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    4    1
[2,]    8    5    2
[3,]    9    6    3
```

In `C++` using Eigen I can do it with a loop

```
Eigen::MatrixXd m1(3, 3);
Eigen::MatrixXd m2(3, 3);
m1 << 1, 4, 7,
      2, 5, 8,
      3, 6, 9;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    m2.col(i) =  m1.col(2 - i);
}

return m2;
```

Is there a better way of doing it? I looked also the `Eigen::Array` documentation but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks, Marco

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `m1.rowwise().reverse()` Similarly use `colwise()` for row reversal.

Comment: Dude! It works really fast. Thanks so much. The funny thing is that colwise sorts the rows like  `m1.colwise().reverse() =    
[1,]    3    6    9
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    1    4    7`  while `m1.rowwise().reverse()` gives the permutation of the columns!  Do you also know how to select only say the last m columns?

Comment: I think there is a 'block' method that allows you to specify start rows, cols and number of each

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it, I remembered. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the question above I forgot to mention that I want to reverse the order of only the last *m* columns. So, an example for the last 2 columns of a 3x3 matrix:
in `R`

```
    > M = matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
    > M
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    4    7
    [2,]    2    5    8
    [3,]    3    6    9
    > M = M[, 3:2]
    > M
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    7    4
    [2,]    8    5
    [3,]    9    6
```

In `C++` using Eigen:

```
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
Eigen::MatrixXd m1(3, 3);
Eigen::MatrixXd m2(3, 2);
m1 << 1, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,
      7, 8, 9;
m2 = m1.block(0, 1, 3, 2).rowwise().reverse();
return m2;
```

Does the trick.
Also `m2 = m1.rowwise().reverse().block(0, 0, 3, 2);` works but is probably less efficient.
For VectorsX? one can use `tail(m)`, `head(m)` or `segment(i, m)`.

Comment: Eigen is an expression template library, so both versions are equally efficient as in both version only the respective sub-matrix will be reversed. Also note the topLeftCorner, leftColumns, middleColumns, topRows, etc. shortcuts of block.